# Permute the words in all strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of text, where you can have multiple words in each element. For example, the array may look like this:

```
let myArray = ['big bad wolf','go home']
```

I want an algorithm that would convert this into a string or another array where it generates all possible combinations of words on the same line. The output would look something like this:

```
big bad wolf
bad big wolf
wolf bad big
wolf big bad
big wolf bad
bad wolf big
go home
home go
```

Comment: You might take a look at what array methods are available in JavaScript and determine which one suits your needs. Then try and use it.

Comment: I can't get my head around what the logic would be. Recursive is a term that comes to mind but I wouldn't know where to start or if indeed it is relevant. I am new to programming again after a long layoff.

Comment: I have just come across Heap's method. It seems perhaps this problem is not as simple as I first hoped. Here is some code showing how to do it for just letters in a word: [link][https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57161/generate-all-possible-combinations-of-letters-in-a-word/57893#57893] And here is some code for a string: [link][https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59615/recursive-function-that-generates-the-permutations-of-a-string]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took the method you have posted in the comments and call it for each element of your array.

*Note:* I renamed it so that it fits more the permutations example and also did a change so splitting at whitespace.

```js
const arr = ["big bad wolf", "go home"];
let res;


arr.forEach((x) => {
res = getPermutations(x);
console.log(res);
})


function swap(words, i, j) {
    const tmp = words[i];
    words[i] = words[j];
    words[j] = tmp;
}

function getPermutations(input) {
    let counter = [],
        permutations = [],
        words = input.split(' '),
        length = words.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        counter[i] = 0;
    }

    permutations.push(input);
    i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        if (counter[i] < i) {
            swap(words, i % 2 === 1 ? counter[i] : 0, i);
            counter[i]++;
            i = 0;
            permutations.push(words.join(' '));
        } else {
            counter[i] = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return permutations;
}
```

Comment: That is working brilliantly thanks! I would like to remove the var from the code as I am only using const and let. Can I just replace all the var's with let or will I need to use the this keyword?

Comment: Yes, use const / let I have also updated my code. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's write a `permute` function that takes an array of strings and returns an array of permutations e.g.,

```js
permute(['big', 'bad', 'wolf']);
//=> [ ["big", "bad", "wolf"]
//=> , ["big", "wolf", "bad"]
//=> , ["bad", "big", "wolf"]
//=> , ["bad", "wolf", "big"]
//=> , ["wolf", "big", "bad"]
//=> , ["wolf", "bad", "big"]]
```

Here's one way of doing it:

```js
const without = (i, xs) => xs.filter((_, j) => j !== i);
const permute =
  xs =>
      xs.length === 1 ? [xs[0]]
    : xs.length === 2 ? [[xs[0], xs[1]], [xs[1], xs[0]]]
                      : xs.flatMap((xx, i, xxs) =>
                          permute(without(i, xxs))
                            .map(ys => [xx, ...ys]));
```

Permuting an array of one or two elements is trivial (so that's your early exit condition there), otherwise iterate and permute the current element with *all* the others (which is why the `without` function is useful).

Splitting `'big bad wolf'` into `['big', 'bad', 'wolf']` is trivial: `str.split(' ')`.
So is joining back `['big', 'bad', 'wolf']` into `'big bad wolf'`: `arr.join(' ')`.

Now all you need to do is:

1. Iterate over an array of strings
2. For each string split it into words
3. Permute those words
4. Join each permutation

```js
['big bad wolf', 'go home']
  .flatMap(str =>
    permute(str.split(' '))
      .map(perm => perm.join(' ')));

//=> [ "big bad wolf"
//=> , "big wolf bad"
//=> , "bad big wolf"
//=> , "bad wolf big"
//=> , "wolf big bad"
//=> , "wolf bad big"
//=> , "go home"
//=> , "home go"]
```

Comment: Really nice solution. At first glance this looked a bit like haskell. I didn't know javascript can be so functional